# fingerprint digital reader connected to a data base

Tags: fingerprint, fingerprinting

I wan't to create a system that allow me to connect several fingerprint reader and send the data to a server (with Arduino).

I need to get a key that I store on my DB and allow me to compare it with other points. I don't want to store the data on the fingerprint.

My real question is more, if you know a fingerprint reader that can send me this instead of an ID stored in the device.

Thanks

Comment: What's data you need to store fingreprint image or fingerprint template or ... ?

Comment: Just some data that allow me to recognize the finger on another fingerprint reader

Answer (score 1):

Lot of fingerprint sensors return "image" of fingerprint.
Some sensors also have an extractor to get a template. Template is a list of [minuitae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minutiae) and other info, extrated from fingreprint image.

[Fingerprint recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint_recognition) is done by comparing template.
There's a open-source extractor provided by NIST: [NBIS](http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/ig/nbis.cfm)

There's a lot of fingerprint sensor providers as [Futronic](http://www.futronic-tech.com/), [Fingeprints](http://www.fingerprints.com/), [Crossmatch](http://www.crossmatch.com/), [Morpho](http://www.morpho.com/identification/secure-biometric-access/fingerprint-sensors/), ... which return fingerprint image.

Comment: @Thanatheos, is it useful ?

Comment: We want to store user's fingerprint in database, so we can validate it on an android device whenever user wanted to access some pages, what are the step involved to store user's fingerprint on web browser?